# What is org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.support.BlobByteArrayType good for?

Tags: java, hibernate, spring, blob

What is [org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.support.BlobByteArrayType](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/api/index.html?org/springframework/orm/hibernate3/support/BlobByteArrayType.html) good for?
Why not map a `byte[]` as the Hibernate basic type "[binary](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/core/reference/en/html/mapping.html#mapping-types-basictypes)"?

What  are the differences? When to use which?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The BlobByteArrayType lets you map arbitrary byte array into a Blob field in the database. The binary type of hibernate allows you to map a byte array into a [varbinary](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/binary-varbinary.html) field.

In [MySQL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/blob.html), Blob is very similar to varbinary, but it can grow as much as you like.

Comment: Thanks -- I realize now that I probably asked the wrong question... %]